# Override Magento Adminhtml Controller

Tags: adminhtml, admin-controller

I'm trying to override the Product Review Controller from Magento Backend, however the new controller is never called, I followed the exact steps on this [post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/4996/rewrite-catalog-product-review-controller-does-nothing), however it does not seem to work, and the new controller is never called. I can see the Edit Review form action attribute from the backend page is stil `<form id="edit_form" action="http://appfactory.loc/index.php/admin/catalog_product_review/save/id/1/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">`. Not sure whether this should reflect the new controller URL or path or whether this is handled internally by Magento.

My code is as simple as:

**appfactory-magento\app\code\local\AppFactory\Basic\etc\config.xml**

```
...

    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml> 
                <args> 
                    <modules> 
                        <AppFactory_Basic after="Mage_Adminhtml">AppFactory_Basic_Adminhtml</AppFactory_Basic>
                    </modules> 
                </args> 
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>

...
```

**app\code\local\AppFactory\Basic\controllers\Adminhtml\Catalog\Product\ReviewController.php**

```
require_once 'Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Product/ReviewController.php';


class AppFactory_Basic_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_ReviewController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_ReviewController
{


    public function saveAction()
    {
        Mage::Helper('basic/log')->log('You finally did it');
    }

}
```

Might be relevant as well, but doesnt think it affect anything:
**app\code\local\AppFactory\Basic\Block\Adminhtml\Review\Edit\Form.php**

```
class AppFactory_Basic_Block_Adminhtml_Review_Edit_Form extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form
{
    protected function _prepareForm()
    {

        $review = Mage::registry('review_data');
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($review->getEntityPkValue());
        $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($review->getCustomerId());

        $form = new Varien_Data_Form(array(
            'id'        => 'edit_form',
            'action'    => $this->getUrl('*/*/save', array('id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id'), 'ret' => Mage::registry('ret'))),
            'method'    => 'post',
            'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'
        ));


        $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('review_details', array('legend' => Mage::helper('review')->__('Review Details'), 'class' => 'fieldset-wide'));


        $fieldset->addField('product_name', 'note', array(
            'label'     => Mage::helper('review')->__('Product'),
            'text'      => '<a href="' . $this->getUrl('*/catalog_product/edit', array('id' => $product->getId())) . '" onclick="this.target=\'blank\'">' . $product->getName() . '</a>'
        ));

        if ($customer->getId()) {
            $customerText = Mage::helper('review')->__('<a href="%1$s" onclick="this.target=\'blank\'">%2$s %3$s</a> <a href="mailto:%4$s">(%4$s)</a>', $this->getUrl('*/customer/edit', array('id' => $customer->getId(), 'active_tab'=>'review')), $this->escapeHtml($customer->getFirstname()), $this->escapeHtml($customer->getLastname()), $this->escapeHtml($customer->getEmail()));
        } else {
            if (is_null($review->getCustomerId())) {
                $customerText = Mage::helper('review')->__('Guest');
            } elseif ($review->getCustomerId() == 0) {
                $customerText = Mage::helper('review')->__('Administrator');
            }
        }



        $fieldset->addField('customer', 'note', array(
            'label'     => Mage::helper('review')->__('Posted By'),
            'text'      => $customerText,
        ));

        /* 
         * added new image custom field 
         * 
         */
       if(Mage::helper("reviewimage")->getActive() == '1'){

            $imageUrl = Mage::getBaseUrl("media").'reviewimages/'.$review->getReviewimage();
            $imageName = $review->getReviewimage();

            $imageResized = Mage::getBaseDir('media').DS."creviewimages".DS.$imageName;
            $dirImg = Mage::getBaseDir().str_replace("/",DS,strstr($imageUrl,'/media'));

            if (!file_exists($imageResized)&&file_exists($dirImg)) {
                $imageObj = new Varien_Image($dirImg);
                $imageObj->constrainOnly(TRUE);
                $imageObj->keepAspectRatio(TRUE);
                $imageObj->keepFrame(FALSE);
                $Resolution = Mage::helper("reviewimage")->getResolution();
                $imageObj->resize($Resolution);
                $imageObj->save($imageResized);
            }
            $newImageUrl = Mage::getBaseUrl('media')."creviewimages/".$imageName;

            $image= "<image src='".$newImageUrl."'>";

            $fieldset->addField('reviewimage', 'note', array(
                'label'     => Mage::helper('review')->__('Posted Review Image'),
                'text'      => $image,
            ));

            $fieldset->addField('appfactory_reviewimage', 'file', array(
                    'label'     => 'AppFactory Review Photo',
                    'required'  => false,
                    'name'      => 'appfactory_reviewimage',
            )); 

       }
            /* 
         * added new image custom field 
         * 
         */

        $fieldset->addField('summary_rating', 'note', array(
            'label'     => Mage::helper('review')->__('Summary Rating'),
            'text'      => $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/review_rating_summary')->toHtml(),
        ));

        $fieldset->addField('detailed_rating', 'note', array(
            'label'     => Mage::helper('review')->__('Detailed Rating'),
            'required'  => true,
            'text'      => '<div id="rating_detail">'
                           . $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/review_rating_detailed')->toHtml()
                           . '</div>',
        ));


        $fieldset->addField('status_id', 'select', array(
            'label'     => Mage::helper('review')->__('Status'),
            'required'  => true,
            'name'      => 'status_id',
            'values'    => Mage::helper('review')->getReviewStatusesOptionArray(),
        ));

        /**
         * Check is single store mode
         */
        if (!Mage::app()->isSingleStoreMode()) {
            $field = $fieldset->addField('select_stores', 'multiselect', array(
                'label'     => Mage::helper('review')->__('Visible In'),
                'required'  => true,
                'name'      => 'stores[]',
                'values'    => Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/system_store')->getStoreValuesForForm(),
            ));
            $renderer = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/store_switcher_form_renderer_fieldset_element');
            $field->setRenderer($renderer);
            $review->setSelectStores($review->getStores());
        }
        else {
            $fieldset->addField('select_stores', 'hidden', array(
                'name'      => 'stores[]',
                'value'     => Mage::app()->getStore(true)->getId()
            ));
            $review->setSelectStores(Mage::app()->getStore(true)->getId());
        }

        $fieldset->addField('nickname', 'text', array(
            'label'     => Mage::helper('review')->__('Nickname'),
            'required'  => true,
            'name'      => 'nickname'
        ));

        $fieldset->addField('title', 'text', array(
            'label'     => Mage::helper('review')->__('Summary of Review'),
            'required'  => true,
            'name'      => 'title',
        ));

        $fieldset->addField('detail', 'textarea', array(
            'label'     => Mage::helper('review')->__('Review'),
            'required'  => true,
            'name'      => 'detail',
            'style'     => 'height:24em;',
        ));

        $form->setUseContainer(true);
        $form->setValues($review->getData());
        $this->setForm($form);
        return parent::_prepareForm();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `config.xml` 
Problem is this line

```
<AppFactory_Basic after="Mage_Adminhtml">AppFactory_Basic_Adminhtml</AppFactory_Basic>
```

should be

```
<AppFactory_Basic before="Mage_Adminhtml">AppFactory_Basic_Adminhtml</AppFactory_Basic>
```

Comment: oh my god, it works. Can you share the difference between After and Before and how Magento handle this?

Comment: I am not sure but may be it  indicates that `AppFactory_Basic` controller will load before `Mage_Adminhtml`.